# NoMethodError in CommentsController#new undefined method `text' for #<Comment id: nil, author: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, erb

I'm trying to use rails with react, just by adding a comments section to the app i'm working on. The `/comments` page works. But when I try to make a new comment. I get this error. I went back to the guide I'm using and doesn't explain anything about this. I'm new to rails and react so if someone could help me out I would appreciate it.

Application Trace:

```
app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:20:in `block in_app_views_comments__form_html_erb__930297241_104622300'
app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb__930297241_104622300'
app/views/comments/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_comments_new_html_erb__151456299_104688260'
```

comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /comments
    # GET /comments.json
    def index
        @comments = Comment.all
    end

    # GET /comments/1
    # GET /comments/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /comments/new
    def new
        @comment = Comment.new
    end

    # GET /comments/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /comments
    # POST /comments.json
    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @comment.save
                format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
    # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @comment.update(comment_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
            else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /comments/1
    # DELETE /comments/1.json
    def destroy
        @comment.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_comment
            @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment_text)
        end
end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

<ul>
    <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment_text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment_text %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Comment</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', comments_path %>
```

[timestamp]_create_comments.rb:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :comments do |t|
            t.string :author
            t.text :comment_text

            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem originates with your schema/migration. The line:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :text)
```

suggests that you have a column named text, which is a datatype in Rails. You should pick a name like "comment_text" for that column that doesn't echo the name of a datatype.

It's also possible that you transposed the datatype and the column name in your migration.

Comment: I've destroyed the Comment scaffold and regenerated it with the column `comment_text`. But now the error is `undefined method comment_text`

Comment: Please post the migration file. You would also have had to edit your strong parameters method in your controller: params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment_text)

Comment: I've noticed that for some reason I cannot have both migration file and be able to run the migration command. When I delete the migration file and run migrate, I get the error that I posted above but it doesn't make a migration file. When I keep the migration file and run migrate the terminal, the terminal gives me a duplicate table error and the web page gives me an error telling me to run the migrate command.

Comment: Everything in your migration file seems to be in order. If you don't have anything in your database that you wish to keep, at this point, I'd recommend doing rake db:drop db:create db:migrate and see how that goes. Running a migration against a database where the migration has already been run would cause the duplicate table error. Dropping the database would take you to square one and avoid that particular problem.

Comment: I tried db:drop but I got `PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR: database <db_name> is being accessed by other users
DETAIL: There is 1 other session using the database.` I tried solving this error by looking it up but I haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: Do you have multiple terminal windows open where your application is running?

Comment: Yes I have, I closed them and tried running db:drop but now I'm getting this error `could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"? `

Comment: You're on to a new problem now, which should be posted in a new Stack Overflow question. However, my best guess is that your postgres server either isn't running or you have a configuration problem. Try running ps axf | grep postgres to see if you have postgres processes running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73711/discussion-between-user2361174-and-marsatomic).